# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable (imblearn generator)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, imbalanced-data

I am dealing with imbalanced text-based dataset. I used tensorflow balanced batch generator to create a balanced batch when training a model as follow:

```
batch_generator, steps_per_epoch = balanced_batch_generator(training_x, training_y, BATCH,
                                                                random_state=42)

 def build_model():

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([


        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_seq_len,
                                  embeddings_initializer='glorot_uniform'),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),  # average across the vector to flatten it out (faster)



        tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                              kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.1)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                              kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.1)),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') 
    ])
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
                  metrics=metrics)

    model.summary()
    return model




 callback_history = build_model().fit_generator(batch_generator,
                                                   steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                                                   epochs=nu_epochs,
                                                   verbose=1)
```

But got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Is it the only line of error? Where does it appear?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani it comes after model summary, the last line of error is  ` ine 225, in <listcomp>
    return [X[idx] for idx in key]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable `